# javadoc: how to use it to document ONE single java file on Window 7?

Tags: java, javadoc

I'm trying to use javadoc to document one single java file on window 7,to simplify things, I only use the following simple command:

```
javadoc Attr.java
```

However, javadoc gives me **IllegalArgumentException** without detailed where it is wrong, actually, the file I used is copied from The Java Programming. So, I'm wondering what is required to use "javadoc" comand in the window environement.

It seems to be working at first ...

```
Loading source file Attr.java...
Constructing Javadoc information...
Standard Doclet version 1.6.0_20
Building tree for all the packages and classes...
Generating Attr.html...
```

But then it starts throwing errors like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at sun.net.www.ParseUtil.decode(ParseUtil.java:189)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:958)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:328)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:322)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:299)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:145)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:385)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1003)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:1193)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport$4.run(SecuritySupport.java:96)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport.getResourceAsStream(SecuritySupport.java:89)
        at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findJarServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:250)
        at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:223)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:128)
```

Here is the java test file I used:

```
/**
 * An <code>Attr</code> object defines an attribute as a
 * name/value pair, where the name is a <code>String</code>
 * and the value an arbitrary <code>Object</code>.
 *
 * @version 1.1
 * @author Plato
 * @since 1.0
 */
public class Attr {
    /** The attribute name. */
    private final String name;
    /** The attribute value. */
    private Object value = null;

    /**
     * Creates a new attribute with the given name and an
     * initial value of <code>null</code>.
     * @see Attr#Attr(String,Object)
     */
    public Attr(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new attribute with the given name and
     * initial value.
     * @see Attr#Attr(String)
     */
    public Attr(String name, Object value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    /** Returns this attribute's name. */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /** Returns this attribute's value. */
    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of this attribute.  Changes the
     * value returned by calls to {@link #getValue}.
     * @param newValue  The new value for the attribute.
     * @return  The original value.
     * @see #getValue()
     */
    public Object setValue(Object newValue) {
        Object oldVal = value;
        value = newValue;
        return oldVal;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a string of the form <code>name=value</code>.
     */
    public String toString() {
        return name + "='" + value + "'";
    }
}
```

/*=====
**SOLUTIONS - Thanks to Michael Borgwardt**
=========*/

first issue:

```
set CLASSPATH=.
```

then

```
javadoc Attr.java
```

Comment: also don't forget the -d [OutputDir] or it will dump the whole mess in your current directory.

Comment: worked fine under windows7 for me.  JDK 1.6.0_21, but that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hm... considering that the error happens in a `ParseUtil` called by the `URLClassLoader`: is it possible that you have a `CLASSPATH` environment variable set whose content is malformed? Try this:

```
javadoc -classpath . Attr.java
```

Comment: @john: have you looked at the environment variable? Do try resetting it with the command "set CLASSPATH="

Comment: yes, Michael, it worked!  THANK YOU!!! I think I added too many jars to the path.....

Comment: @john: this kind of thing is why you should not use the CLASSPATH environment variable at all, it's unfortunate that many Java novices learn about it from outdated tutorials.

Comment: Hi Michael, could enlighten me on the alternatives if I do not use classpath and I need to access .jars? Thank you again!

Comment: @john: use the command line -classpath switch as in my example above. For more complex cases where retyping it would be annoying, you can use a script or (better) automate the various build steps via Apache Ant.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your working directory is the same as the directory containing Attr.java. The command should work as stated then.

Comment: i tried again, every thing is so simple. I just wonder if the problem is with Window 7 environment.

Comment: That exception is very weird indeed. Can you try the patch 21? Maybe your VM is botched...

Answer (score 0):

You can also try :-

```
javadoc <yourAbsPathToJavaFile>.java
```

It had worked for me.